# Not able to login as jenkins user

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have jenkins installed on amazon ec2 instance but i am not able to login as jenkins user.I used this command

```
 sudo su - jenkins
```

but it is taking me to bash instead of logging me as a jenkis user
[image]

Comment: What do you expect? Are you used to work on the terminal?

Comment: @stephenking i expect it to login as jenkins@ip-172-20-0-211

Comment: Please don't add text output as screen shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are logged in as `jenkins` user, as you verified using `whoami`.

The bash prompt for this user is just not configured to include the user name, but only displays the shell version.

Try the following:

```
[root@ip-172-20-0-211 ~]# echo $PS1
\[\u@\h \w .... some more cryptic stuff
```

Copy this output and paste it here

```
[root@ip-172-20-0-211 ~]# sudo su - jenkins
-bash-4.2$ export PS1="\[\u@\h \w .... some more cryptic stuff"
```

and the next line should look similar to the following:

```
[jenkins@ip-172-20-0-211 ~]
```

Read more about the prompt e.g. [here](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-prompt-basics).

Comment: it worked one time but once i logged out it was again taking me to bash instead of jenkins@.Is there any way we can add this permanently

Comment: Yes. Add it to a file `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` (or `.profile` in general). Which one to use depends on your Linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log in as Jenkins, you can do so with

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

On jenkins's home folder `/var/lib/jenkins` create this file `.bashrc` and add the following content to it and save it, that's it, try again `sudo su -` and then `sudo su jenkins` and you will see `[jenkins@your-ip root]$` instead of `bash-4.2$`.

Here the step-by-step:
Go to jenkins' home folder:

> `bash-4.2$` cd /var/lib/jenkins

Then create the **.bashrc** file there:

> `bash-4.2$` echo > .bashrc

Edit the file that you've created:

> `bash-4.2$` nano .bashrc

Add the following content to it then save it:

```
# .bashrc
 
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
 
# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=
 
# User specific aliases and functions
```

Now try to logout and login again to the user:

> `bash-4.2$` sudo su -
>
> `[root@your-ip ~]#` sudo su jenkins
>
> `[jenkins@your-ip root]$`